# Android Management API: How to prevent the initial apps to be uninstalled during enrollment?

Tags: android, google-apis-explorer, android-management-api

Is there any way to keep all the initial apps besides those mentioned within the policy? I've inspected all the possibly related properties such as *blockApplicationsEnabled* and *playStoreMode*, but couldn't find a way.

Comment: Have you tried using PlayStoreMode "BLACKLIST" in your policy? According to docs: *"All apps are available and any app that should not be on the device should be explicitly marked as 'BLOCKED' in the applications policy."*

https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#PlayStoreMode

Comment: @anro yes, I have, it just allows downloading any app, but still uninstalls the initial ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While generating the QR Code for enrollment, make sure you set `"android.app.extra.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED": true`

This will make sure to tell the mobile device management application to skip the disabling of system apps during provisioning when set to true.